# `sizeof` all types in C++ application

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, windbg

Debugging a suspected memory leak in Windows C++ application, I've managed to get heap allocations statistics that looks like that (this is result of `!heap -stat -h ...` command executed for relevant heap in WinDbg):

```
size     #blocks     total     ( %) (percent of total busy bytes)
651 686f0 - 293a51f0  (54.65)
260 68701 - f80a260  (20.55)
11c 68705 - 73dc98c  (9.60)
...
```

From what I know about the application, this indeed looks pretty much like a leak, but given that I'm only working with a dump that has no [user stack trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/create-user-mode-stack-trace-database) information, I'm stuck to guesswork and other methods.

One thing I can think about is to understand which class or struct these allocations of 0x651 or 0x260 bytes refer to, as these allocations seem to look pretty suspicious. A straightforward approach that I can think of is to list every class/struct listed in my application and get `sizeof` results for it.

Is there any simple way to do that (i.e. without resorting to manual extraction of structs/classes with some sort of C++ parser (or worse, regexps), and running `sizeof` on it in a compiler or something similar)?

Comment: Very interesting question, I'm thrilled about the result :D

Comment: I cant think of. I typically run valgrind on these kind of code for static leak detection. Or run the application under some memory instrumentation e.g. memcheck, valgrind runtime. http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this is relatively complex application with many different control flows. Running Valgrind on Linux build of it, either on the application itself, or its test suite, yields nothing — so it's probably either something Windows-specific, or some rare condition that occurs only under specific conditions that I can't reproduce under Valgrind.

Comment: Sounds more like an allocation of character or dynamic array, not of a single struct.  0x615 is 1,617 bytes -- can you find a struct that is of this size?

Comment: Do you mean the aggregated size of all types, or the aggregated size of the instances of all types?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: why do you think about aggregated sizes? Did OP mention that he wants to aggregate something?

Comment: @Thomas I made the comment because I didn't understand what the OP was asking about, and wanted them to clarify. That's what comments are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way of listing all types along with all sizes.

However, you can use `x` (examine symbols) with the `/s` option to find types that match the size you're interested in.

Example:

```
0:004> x /d /s 0n28 ole32!*
[...]
00000000`76a06e78 ole32!IViewObject2_StubThunkTable = <function> *[7]
00000000`769d97fc ole32!g_wszInprocHandler16 = wchar_t [14] "InprocHandler"
00000000`76a96194 ole32!g_wszIconReference = wchar_t [14] "IconReference"
```

So in your case, the command would be

```
x /s 651 <mydll>!*
```

or maybe even

```
x /s 651 *!*
```

if you don't suspect a specific DLL.

A similar approach would be `dt -e -s 0n28 ole32!*`, but it doesn't take `*!*` as an argument.

Unfortunately, it's still possible that there is no such type, because

- memory was allocated by `malloc()`
- it's just a bunch of identical strings or other objects that are allocated dynamically
- ...

In that case, you might want to try `!heap -flt s 651` and have a look at the `UserPtr` of some of them.

Example:

```
0:004> !heap -flt s 2268
    _HEAP @ 130000
              HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags            UserPtr UserSize - state
        0000000000131330 0229 0000  [00]   0000000000131360    02268 - (busy)
    _HEAP @ 20000

0:004> db 0000000000131360    L30
00000000`00131360  3d 00 3a 00 3a 00 3d 00-3a 00 3a 00 5c 00 00 00  =.:.:.=.:.:.\...
00000000`00131370  41 00 4c 00 4c 00 55 00-53 00 45 00 52 00 53 00  A.L.L.U.S.E.R.S.
00000000`00131380  50 00 52 00 4f 00 46 00-49 00 4c 00 45 00 3d 00  P.R.O.F.I.L.E.=.
```

Comment: To add to that, doing `db` on some `UserPtrs` is a good way to get a feel for what memory is leaking. If it's a string, then it should be pretty obvious. If not, then there's still hope. If the leaked objects have any `virtual` methods, then `dps UserPtr` should reveal a `vptr` with the class name. [heap_stat.py](https://github.com/goldshtn/windbg-extensions/blob/master/heap_stat.py) automates this process.

Comment: Thanks! `x` command approach seems to be not exactly working (as it lists symbols, i.e. instances with concrete addresses in memory, not types — so typically that works for functions and static/global allocations), but `dt -e -s` approach was right on the spot!